# What does !!! do in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Silly me - some time ago, I have written the following code:

```
 result[[sheet]] <- tibble::add_row(
          result[[sheet]],
          !!!unlist(
            xmlList[[sheetList]][[i]]
          )
        )
```

Now I have to re-write it (breaking changes in the tibble package) and do not remember, what the `!!!` was doing. I think it was something from the `tidyverse`, but it I did not find a way to google for `!!!`.

Can somebody enlighten me?

Thanks.

Comment: It is doing the evaluation of named vector/list of key/value pairs

Comment: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting - see section 19.4.5

Comment: True - that was it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To get the docs: `help("!!!")`

Comment: Why am I always forgetting the `help()` function...